# Script for a close button which will work both for colorbox popup and normal popup in a asp.net and vb.net application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, popup, colorbox

I have a page which opens as a popup from two different area. In the first area it opens as a colorbox popup. And from the second one it opens inside another simple javascript popup.

The page was previously designed as a colorbox popup. And the close button designed for the page works only when it opens as colorbox popup.

```
        <a href="javascript:parent.$.colorbox.close();" class="btn" title="Close Window">Cancel</a>
```

Problem is the close button does not work when it opens inside another simple popup. I normally use the following line of code for the close button of normal simple popup.

```
           <a class="btn" href="javascript:window.close();">Close</a>
```

That works when the page opens inside anohter normal javascript popup but that doesnot work when the popup opens as a colorbox popup.

Is there any script that will work in both cases?

I have tried to close the popup window via vb.net by using the following code .

asp.net line of code

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ID="uxClose"
        Text="Close Window via Asp" CssClass="btn" />
```

VB.net code

```
Protected Sub uxClose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uxClose.Click
    If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.close();", True)

   End Sub
```

that does not work.I have also tried

```
 Protected Sub uxClose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uxClose.Click
    If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub
   Me.close()
 End Sub
```

but that gives error message

I will appreciate your kind co operation

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colorbox plugin adds an overlay with an id of `cboxOverlay`. Why don't you just check to see if it exists, and if does - there is a colorbox open, if not, then you can close the other type of popup.

```
function isColorbox(){

    return $('#cboxOverlay').length;

}
```

Now you can do this...

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function(){

    if (isColorbox()){

        $.colorbox.close();

    } else {

        // using your original code for non-colorboxes
        window.close()
    }
});
```